# IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, text-to-speech

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;

public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Object[] rawMsgs = (Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");

        for (Object raw : rawMsgs) {
            SmsMessage message  = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])raw);

            Log.v("[SMS]:", message.getMessageBody());

            TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, null);

        }
    }
}
```

I get an error when I try to initialize `TextToSpeech`. Apparently, I can't bind to services when in a `BroadcastReceiver`. Is there any workaround for this?